# Ascw returns "Cannot convert to 'Integer'." in Watch or Immediate

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I have following sample code

```
Dim q As Char = "a"
Dim res As String = CStr(AscW(q))
```

`res` contains correctly "97" but when I use `AscW(q)` in watch or immediate it returns message: `Cannot convert to 'Integer'.`

Is it a bug or Visual Studio or am I doing something not correctly?

How can I see a character code in Immediate.

**Note**
The code presented is just an example. I found the problem when trying to see Character code in the Watch Window.

Comment: Have you tried with val(q)?

Comment: @coder In Watch Returns 0 as expected.

Comment: I have read your last note. Can you please include in your update all the code you are using? I have observed the problems you refer while relying on old functions (as explained in my answer), but not on .NET ones. Thus the Character type shouldn't really matter but the code/functions you use to interact with these variables.

Comment: @varocarbas The code I am realy using is: `String.Format("{0} U+{1:x4} {1}", c, AscW(c))`. I found problem when stepping through it.

Comment: As said, AscW triggers this behaviour. If you analyse the elements of this line via right-click, quickwatch, you would see that AscW is wrong, U+{1:x4} is wrong (not sure what you are intending to do there but this does not look like VB.NET) and String.Format is wrong (because some of its inputs are wrong) and all the other bits are right.

Comment: It works in VB 2008 -- those two lines and shift-F9 display for AscW(q) show 97.

Comment: @xpda no they don't (as the OP is claiming at least). If you run these two lines in VS 2008, set a break point in Dim res As String = CStr(AscW(q)), right click on this line and select QuickWatch, you would see what the OP means. It does not have any relevant effect (as explained in my answer and in the multiple comments I have written), but this is what the OP was asking for: why he gets errors in the debugging options (Immediate Window and QuickWatch)?

Comment: @xpda although well... I am not sure about what the OP is after. He asked whether he was doing something wrong, I said that no (although shouldn't use certain "old functions", like CStr). He insisted in that he wanted the "errors" (not really such a thing) to not appear anyway (and I proposed alternatives). I spent a relevant amount of time coming over and over the same ideas. But he seems to not be happy with all this, apparently he is expecting something different, like someone telling him that he did things wrongly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a workaround, how about the command

```
? System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(q)
```

I personally believe that any acceptable VB.Net code should be acceptable in the Immediate window and really don't understand why AscW is causing errors when VB.Net offers no equivalent (e.g. in C#, but not VB.Net, you can cast a Char variable to an Integer to get the character code).

Comment: `? System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(q)(0)+256*System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(q)(1)` is ugly but works. I still wonder why AscW is returning exception.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing everything right (and the outputs will be OK in any case), although you are using old VB code. If you need functionalities like `AscW` (, `Asc`, `ChrW`, etc.), you would have to rely on this "old code" to get what you want (directly or via `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings` which, btw, does not show a different behaviour). But, in any other case, you should avoid the utilisation of this old code.

Test these two lines in the Immediate Window:

```
Dim res As String = CStr(5)
res = 5.ToString()
```

As you can see, you get an "error" (VS 2010, right-click on the line and select "QuickWatch") in the first line (old version), but not in the second one (.NET version).

Thus, the behaviour you observed can be considered as an inoffensive bug (no real effects in the execution) more or less understandable if you analyse the situation (you are asking a certain language (VB.NET) to support all its own features and the ones from an old language (VB); with the old one, some secondary functionalities might not be perfect).

Comment: So what to use to see a character code in Watch or Immediate?

Comment: @IvanH as commented above: please tell me the function you are using. A character-type variable should work fine; but if you put it in an old VB function (like AscW), you would observe "this issue". In this case there is no .NET (ACCURATE) replacement and thus you will have to live with it (or build your own method); but, in most of the other cases, there might be a replacement. Please, write down the exact code you are using, such that I can know what we are talking about.

Comment: I need to write something as `? AscW(q)` to the `Immediate Window` and get the code (97) instead of the "Cannot convert to 'Integer'."

Comment: @IvanH I am not getting this error, I am getting a different one. In any case, as explained, this seems to be a limitation associated with using old VB. AscW is an old VB function. Unfortunately, there is no accurate replacement for AscW in .NET. Thus you should live with this Immediate Window problem (which, on the hand, has no effect on the execution) or create your own method performing what AscW does. In all the other cases, you should rely on new .NET code, instead in all VB one. The maximum I can do is suggesting a .NET equivalent if you explain me what you want exactly.

Comment: What do you mean by old VB I am using VB.NET in VS2012 with target framework 4.5. VS2010 with targer framework 3.5 have the same behavior. AscW behaves correctly (in Immediate or Watch) in your case?

Comment: @IvanH What I mean is that this function was created in the old VB, works fine in old VB and does not belong to what the .NET is about. For example: Len(string) is old VB, string.Length is the new .NET; CStr(number) is old VB and number.ToString() is new .NET. In the old VB functions, the starting index is usually 1; in the .NET equivalences, the starting index is 0; etc. VS (and VB.NET) supports all these functions since the first .NET version. This is all what I am saying

Comment: OK I got it. But still there is a question How can I see a character code in Immediate?

Comment: @IvanH in any case bear in mind that the difference old/new is not too clear (mainly in case where the given functionalities are not duplicated). I have been testing your String.Format above (which is used in .NET without any problems because there is no clear equivalence) and it also shows these problems (in the QuickWatch). Anyway... you have asked why? And I have proposed you a solution. I have performed the replacement of the given functions when possible (e.g., CStr, Val, Len, etc.) and I have confirmed that this behaviour does not persist. ChrW cannot be replaced.

Comment: @IvanH I insist: you can see character code (I guess that you mean char-type variables) as far as you use "new functions". As said, I have tested your code above, and String.Format (and AscW) triggers this error anyway, so cannot do anything to avoid that (other than removing String.Format and intending to rely on some kind of mixed approach delivering the same). You asked whether you are doing everything rightly and my answer is: YES. BUT, if possible, rely on new functions. If not possible, don't worry but accept the consequences (e.g., peculiar messages in Immediate Window).

Comment: What new function should I use to get character code(unicode) instead of AscW?

Comment: @IvanH Please, read my answer and you will understand perfectly what I think and what options you have (in my opinion). I told you: there is no replacement for AscW. There are functions delivering pretty-close results (to AscW and to Asc) but there is no true .NET equivalence. You will have to live with it or create your own function delivering the AscW functionality. All this having crystal clear the idea that the actual execution (the results from your program) will not be affected at all.